# Using SASS/SCSS to alter a .js class, within a nested structure

Tags: css, sass, hierarchy

A quick one (hopefully).

I have something like:

```
.front-cards-content {
  .front-card-content {
    &:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
      .card-content-icon {
        strong {
          &:hover {
            // Do something...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `// Do something` is heavily nested within relevant parents.

If I wanted to ensure that that something only occurred when JavaScript was enabled, I could use the `.js` class that's attached to my `<html>` tag.

However, everything else in this hierarchy should be available, regardless of whether the `.js` switch is present or not.

I'm aware I can simply copy and paste the whole thing, and add the `.js` to the very start of the nested classes, but that seems very counter intuitive.

Is there a way to get around doing that? To somehow add the `.js` to the root of the hierarchy I'm working in, without needing to copy and paste it all (which could lead to maintenance issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the SASS ampersand parent selector.
It'll look for the .js class as any parent of the top selector (.front-cards-content), so for example if you had `<html class="js">`.

```
.front-cards-content {
  .front-card-content {
    &:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
      .card-content-icon {
        strong {
          &:hover {
            // Do something...
            .js & {
              // Do something different if JS is a parent of top selector (e.g. in html or body tag
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mc2zejf7/1/

Comment: Of course! D'oh! -- It's been a long day. Thanks a bunch! :-)